# How to check if a string is date?

Tags: java, regex

I am having string like

```
"11-04-2015 22:01:13:053" or "32476347656435"
```

How can I check if string is Date?
Checking String if it is numeric using regex

```
String regex = "[0-9]+";
```

Comment: Use Date functions instead of regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: @ashutosh I believe that question covers string to date conversion, not validation.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Other person are also correct

This is your answer

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class date {
    public static boolean isValidDate(String inDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:ms");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        try {
            dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(isValidDate("20-01-2014"));
        System.out.println(isValidDate("11-04-2015 22:01:33:023"));

        System.out.println(isValidDate("32476347656435"));
    }
}
```

Comment: There is multiple date formats so yo have to check a variety of them e.g. `yyyy/MM/dd`

Comment: Never use exceptions for data flowing. They are hurts performance.

Comment: There are bugs in the code. It rejects the fully valid `11-04-2015 22:01:33:999`. And it accepts all of the following three, which may or may not be desired (1) `11-04-2015 22:01:33:023 and some nonsense here` (2) `1-4-5 2:1:3:23` (3) `011-004-22001155 22:001:33:500023`. The bugs are mainly due to the confusing and poor design of `SimpleDateFormat`. You should avoid using that class.

Answer (score 5):

### java.time

It’s about time someone provides the modern answer. The `SimpleDateFormat` class mentioned in a couple of the other answers is notoriously troublesome and fortunately now long outdated. Instead the modern solution uses java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss:SSS");

    String stringToTest = "11-04-2015 22:01:13:053";

    try {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringToTest, formatter);
        System.out.println("The string is a date and time: " + dateTime);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        System.out.println("The string is not a date and time: " + dtpe.getMessage());
    }
```

Output from this snippet is:

> The string is a date and time: 2015-04-11T22:01:13.053

Suppose that instead the string was defined as:

```
    String stringToTest = "32476347656435";
```

Now the output is:

> The string is not a date and time: Text '32476347656435' could not be parsed at index 2

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions:

- Use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and try to convert the `String` to `Date`. If no `ParseException` is thrown the format is correct.
- Use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to parse the `String`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Commons Validator. It provides validation framework for validating date, time, numbers, currency, IP address, email, and URL.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Example:

```
assertTrue(GenericValidator.isDate("2019-02-28", "yyyy-MM-dd", true))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for dates it ends up doing a try { parse } catch (ParseException) {} as the other solutions

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to actually try to parse it to a date with `DateTime.TryParse()`.

```
String d = "11-04-2015 22:01:13:053";

DateTime dt = new DateTime();

if (DateTime.TryParse(d, out dt)) { 
    /// yes, it's a date, do something here... 
} else {
    // no, it's not a date, do something else here... 
}
```

Comment: This solution is only useful to check if a string with a specific format can be interpretted as a valid date. Dates can be written in so many ways, so a more intelligent match routine is probably what is called for. Further more, some strings that represent dates could have multiple interpretations, for example "03/03/08". Is it March 3rd 2008 - or is it 8th of March 2003?

Comment: I believe that `DateTime.TryParse` is a .NET function not accessible from Java. And I believe a Java solution was asked for.